# Will the stack of a C program ever shrink?

Tags: c, stack

I've noticed that every running C program has a private mapping called [stack] that is initially quite small (128k on my machine), but will grow to accomodate any automatic variables (up to the stack size limit). I assume this is where the call stack of my program is located.

However, it doesn't seem to ever shrink back to its original size. Is there any way to free up that memory without terminating the process?

How is the C stack implemented internally; what increases the size of the [stack] mapping on demand? Some compiler generated code, the C library or the operating system? Where is the increase triggered?

*Update*: I'm using Linux 3.0.0, gcc 4.6.1 and glibc6 on x86-64; as this is probably pretty implementation specific, any information on how it works there would be fine.

Comment: All of this depends very strongly on the platform.

Comment: In extreme heat, and on a DeathStation900: yes, it might shrink.

Comment: Yeah, come on, you should have told us what OS and compiler you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux/MMU (in !MMU you cannot grow the stack), the stack is grown in the page fault handler. For x86, whether to grow the stack is decided by the following code from `arch/x86/mm/fault.c:do_page_fault()`:

```
        if (error_code & PF_USER) {
            /*
             * Accessing the stack below %sp is always a bug.
             * The large cushion allows instructions like enter
             * and pusha to work. ("enter $65535, $31" pushes
             * 32 pointers and then decrements %sp by 65535.)
             */
            if (unlikely(address + 65536 + 32 * sizeof(unsigned long) < regs->sp)) {
                    bad_area(regs, error_code, address);
                    return;
            }
    }
    if (unlikely(expand_stack(vma, address))) {
            bad_area(regs, error_code, address);
            return;
    }
```

`expand_stack()` checks the usual RLIMITS (RLIMIT_AS, RLIMIT_STACK, RLIMIT_MEMLOCK), whether LSMs will allow to grow the stack, whether there's too much overcommit, etc..., and finally grows the stack.

Comment: The question was "Will the stack of a C program ever shrink?"

Answer (score 6):

It's implementation specific, but I know of no commonly used platform which shrinks committed stack memory. It is common for stacks to grow on demand but once space is committed it stays committed.

Comment: Is there some usual way how the on-demand growth is implemented? Does a write to some previously unused part of the stack segment trigger a page fault, and is it then increased by the kernel? Or does that happen from user space?

Comment: On x86 at least the standard implementation is via guard pages.

Comment: Ah, I see - that explains why it grows automatically, but never shrinks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you mean on Windows, right? I believe the Linux kernel just sees that the page fault is in `start of stack` + `RLIMIT_STACK`, where I have defined `+` very liberally.

Comment: @ninjalj Yes, I was thinking of Windows implementation. To be fair the original question did not state OS and I assumed that guard pages were the standard approach on other systems.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the Linux kernel is growing the stack segment (only for the main thread). It is not in the compiler (except by incrementing the stack pointer at calls, and ignoring the experimental `-fsplit-stack` option of recent GCC), and not in the libC.

If you are sure your stack has grown too big, and you won't need it, you might perhaps  `munmap` the unused part (but be careful; kernel developers don't think of this so it might not work as expected; in the early 1990-s I remembered having crashed SunOS5.0 on Sparc with such dirty tricks).

And on Linux, x86-64, with a decent machine, you really should not care. The stack is not that big...

My guess is that the stack segment is `mmap`-ed with `MAP_NORESERVE` `MAP_STACK` `MAP_GROWSDOWN` but I may be wrong.