# Find stack usage of some API function call without using any tools etc?

Tags: c

How can you determine the stack usage of a function call from an API that has been provided to you? You do not know what the function looks like and you have access only to the API. For example,

```
    int main() {
      // call some API function  
      some_func_called();

      // rest of your main
    }
```

The only thing that I can think of is by populating the stack memory with a known pattern before calling the function and later checking the stack to see how many bytes of the the known pattern was changed after the function returns. Any other ideas? (This was an interview question)

Comment: "Any other ideas?", while I think your idea's as good as it gets, for the sake of mentioning an alternative - on some OSes you can remove read/write permissions from memory regions in your program, which you could use to shrink usable stack space until some_func_called falls over.  You need to know or guess where the stack can potentially grow to (also a problem for your "known pattern" approach), and if some_func_called() can't be called multiple times, or may not use the same amount of memory each call, then you need to rerun the app while honing in on the failure point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, not fully tested, may have limit problems. Only works if stack pointer decreases by PUSHING, so this is not portable across all hardware...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STK_CNT 65536

size_t STK_fill()
{
    volatile size_t i, cnt = 0;

    volatile u_int32_t fill[STK_CNT];

    for(i = 0; i < STK_CNT; i++)
    {
        fill[i] = 0xDEADBEEFUL;
    }

    return cnt;
}

size_t STK_find()
{
    volatile size_t i, cnt = 0;

    volatile u_int32_t fill[STK_CNT];

    for(i = 0; i < STK_CNT; i++)
    {
        if(fill[i] == 0xDEADBEEFUL)
        {
            cnt++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }

    return ((STK_CNT - cnt) * 4);
}

void victim(char *po_str, const char *pi_str)
{
    char str[1024];

    strcpy(str, "stk_TEST_");
    strcat(str, pi_str);
    strcat(str, "_stk_TEST");

    strcpy(po_str, str);
}

int main()
{
    int  temp;
    int  used;
    char str[4096] = {0};

    temp = (int)STK_fill();
    victim(str, "STK_tst_STK_tst_STK_tst_STK_tst_STK_tst_STK_tst_STK_tst_STK");
    used = (int)STK_find();

    printf("VICTIM function used %d bytes of stack\n", used);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What could be the practical value of this?

Comment: @Meeir: practical value... it might allow some insight into whether a function that's recursive in the source code is optimised to avoid actual recursion at run time, or allow some run-time estimate of the maximum depth of recursion before failure.  It could also be useful insight into the proper size of stack to ask the compiler to allocate (in systems where it's hard-coded), whether for a normal stack or for exception handling.  It might just be useful insight - a sanity check for unexpectedly high memory use indicating unwanted copying.  But, all extremely hackish.

Comment: @Meeir Aalie: <used> variable in <main> holds the number of stack-bytes actually used by the victim function. You may optimize your stack usage of your threads with this function, which I have to do something similar for Embedded Systems BTW. Tony Delroy's comment is also informative...

Comment: @Malkocoglu Yeah can be handy in embedded system where memory is a premium. Thanks for all the responses guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is the most reliable way to do it.

An alternative might be to use the fact that modern OSes tend to grow the stack (i.e. commit memory to it) as needed. See [Will the stack of a C program ever shrink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203110/will-the-stack-of-a-c-program-ever-shrink) Perhaps, having called this function, you could interrogate the OS about the amount of memory committed to the stack. This is, of course, OS-specific, might be architecture-specific, and on the whole is likely to be a lot more fiddly than the first approach.

Comment: The "interrogate the OS" idea assumes that the high watermark from earlier stack usage won't exceed and hide the stack usage of the function to be tested - not generally a workable approach.